# Why DeckPanel doesn't show anything in UiBinder, GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

```
<g:TabBar ui:field="mainTabPanel" />
<g:DeckPanel ui:field="mainDeckPanel" >
     <g:Label text="test"/>
</g:DeckPanel>
```

Only TabBar got visible, DeckPanel shows nothing.

Is it cos DeckPanel only works in Quirks Mode?

The Gwt Doc doesn't say anything about which browser mode DeckPanel support.

I changed to DeckLayoutPanel `<g:DeckLayoutPanel ui:field="mainDeckPanel" >...` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, just 1 line of code

```
mainDeckPanel.showWidget(0);
```

And i done